# Operation not permitted error when deleting as root

Tags: linux, debian, external-hard-drive

I got into a weird situation. I got a 1Tb portable HD filled with some contents. It was used in Windows and as always packed with virus. I tried deleting some folders as root. But the following error returned

```
rm -R RECYCLER/
rm: cannot remove `RECYCLER/S-1-5-21-1659004503-1644491937-725345543-1003/Dc39.pptx': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove `RECYCLER/S-1-5-21-1659004503-1644491937-725345543-1003/Dc58.docx': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove `RECYCLER/S-1-5-21-1659004503-1644491937-725345543-1003/Dc17.JPG': Operation not permitted
```

`ls -l` returned

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xf898cc8b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1      121602   976760536    7  HPFS/NTFS

ls -l RECYCLER/
total 12
drwxrwxrwx 1 user user 12288 Dec 11 21:13 S-1-5-21-1659004503-1644491937-725345543-1003
```

Comment: What is the drive mounted as?

Comment: Its automounted in /media as with NTFS as the FS

Comment: Extended attributes or ACLs on the files?

Comment: Is it possible that your drive is mounted as read-only? Executing `mount` provides this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The directory `RECYCLER/S-1-5-21-1659004503-1644491937-725345543-1003` is presumably read-only. Run `chmod -R u+w RECYCLER` to set write permission on directories, then `rm -rf RECYCLER`.

If this is through a FUSE filesystem, it's possible that only the user who mounted the filesystem has write permission on it. In that case, run `su user rm -rf RECYCLER`.

Comment: When I run `chmod -R u+w RECYCLER` it gives the operation not permitted. I tried even running chown command

Comment: @user61954 NTFS is usually provided through FUSE (via ntfs-3g) these days, so try `su user …` (second paragraph of my answer).

Comment: Installed ntfs-3g and now it works fine :)

Answer (score 8):

This is due to an immutable attribute set for the files. If your filesystem driver allows it, run the command below before removing it.

```
chattr -i RECYCLER/S-1-5-21-1659004503-1644491937-725345543-1003/*
rm -f RECYCLER/S-1-5-21-1659004503-1644491937-725345543-1003/*
```

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some filesystem issues. Try `chkdsk /F [Harddrive]:` on a windows PC.

Example:

`chkdsk /F E:`

Comment: Sorry, I dont have windows

Comment: If it's not going to be used on Windows again, I suggest you backup the useful files and reformat it with ext4 or other Linux-native filesystems.

Comment: The probelem is that its owner uses Windows :D

Answer (score 0):

On debian you can use the `fsck.ntfs` command.

I think the Package is called [NTFSProgs.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntfsprogs)

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem on my Note 3 (Android device) with some files in a folder on the external SD card.  rm produced "operation not permitted" and lsattr produced "inappropriate ioctl for device".

The fix for me was to take the SD card out of the phone and put it into a PC to delete the files.  Worked like a charm.  I know that's not exactly a "linux" solution but it's the only thing that worked. Hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @warren: What question does this not answer? The original *question* does not really ask a question. Implicitly, it asks, "How do I remove contents from a Windows disk?" Dubious is (somewhat anecdotally) answering, "Put the disk back on a Windows system and do it there." It's no less of an answer than [Daniel's first answer](http://superuser.com/a/372674/150988). OK, yes, user61954 says that [s]he doesn't have Windows; hence Dubious's disclaimer that he hopes this will help someone else.

Comment: @Scott - the question is about external hard drives and linux: Dubious' answer is about an SD card from an Android device that needed to be deleted *using* Windows. The answer has nothing to do with the question, and is barely tangentially similar.